# Is the last name Logan Jewish?

Tags: names

My last maiden name is Logan and I want to know if I am of Jewish descent. Logan was my grandmother's last name and she was from New York. I attend synangogue on Saturday having always been drawn to Judiasm.

Comment: Hi Dorothy and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  As Gershon says in his answer, names can be pretty unreliable indicators.  In addition, it matters which grandmother -- Jewish identity is passed through mothers, so your father's mother doesn't affect you (only your mother's mother).

Comment: Comments: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13111674#13111674 et seq. and http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13140790#13140790 et seqq.

Answer (score 4):

There are Jews with last names that sound non Jewish and there are non Jews with last names that sound Jewish. A last name in itself would not prove whether one is a Jew or not. Jewishness is also determined via the mother, and it is possible that a Jewish lady married a non Jewish man by the last name of Logan, and now there is a Jewish Logan.

[Per Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clan_Logan) the name Logan seems to stem from Scotland. Most likely it is not Jewish, however it is always possible. Names were changed when people arrived in the USA. I would recommend that you discuss this with a competent Rabbi and a genalogist, who may be able to help you delve deeper into your past.

> The surname Logan is a territorial name, likely derived from the lands
>   of Logan in present Ayrshire, Scotland. The earliest record of the
>   surname is of Robert Logan who is recorded as witnessing the
>   resignation of the lands of Ingilbristoun in 1204. The name is
>   variously recorded throughout the 13th century

Comment: This reminds me of the well known story of Sean Ferguson - who said, when the Ellis Island immigration officer asked his name "ich schoen vergessen" (I have completely forgotten). As Gershon Gold says, however, Jewishness is via the maternal line, whereas surnames are normally through the paternal line, so there is no real connection.