# I was raised Luthern. My last name is apparently Jewish

Tags: christianity

I am looking for answers. I have discovered my last name is considered a Jewish name. Glasser. I was raised Lutheran,as are all of my family. Is it possible to become Jewish even though I believe in Jesus and the New Testament

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34556/is-the-last-name-logan-jewish

Comment: Jeremy, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/am-i-jewish regarding the general question of how one might determine if one is Jewish. If you suspect that you might be Jewish and want a professional ruling or advice on whether you are, I recommend that you consult a rabbi. We offer potentially-helpful information but [can't make that determination for you](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi).

Comment: you could be called Kohen and still not be Jewish

Comment: It should be noted that Jewish _status_ and Jewish practice are not the same. One could have the Jewish _status_ (if his mother were Jewish or underwent a conversion; see the linked questions in the other comments) even if (s)he does not practice Judaism. Best of luck finding answers.

Comment: Regarding "Is it possible to become Jewish?" see [Is it possible for a Gentile to convert to Judaism?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/is-it-possible-for-a-gentile-to-convert-to-judaism). Again, if you're interested in advice on whether you personally can or should become Jewish, I recommend consulting a rabbi.

Comment: "Is it possible to become Jewish?" - yes. "Is it possible to become Jewish even though I believe in Jesus and the New Testament?" - no.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27135/1713

Comment: Firstly, surnames follow patrilineal descent whereas Judaism is matrilineal so you are probably not born Jewish. In order to convert you have to follow the Jewish Law including the Principles of Faith and the authenticity of the Beis Din and Rabbinic Law and Jewish interpretations which refute any chance of Jesus being the Moshiach.

Comment: Concerning your last name, like many people from Europe it is most likely that the family name came quite late. Actually, when Napolean was conquering Europe one of the things that he required of the conquered peoples was that they adopt a family name. Many people confronted with that choice took the name of their profession. It is quite possible that your ancestors were in the glazing business, meaning makers of glass and windows. Regarding trying to become Jewish while still believing in Christianity, this is prohibited. For a Jew, Christian believes are considered a form of idol worship.